# transfer from wptorrent to PC

Tags: windows-10-mobile, file-transfer

I own a Microsoft Lumia 550 with Windows 10 Mobile. I downloaded some files through wptorrent. Now I want to transfer them to my pc, but I can not find the folder where the files are located.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the files are downloaded into the applications private data folder. Look around the app and look for an option to share the files you have downloaded, such as long pressing them. If you can't find them in the file manager you can try using Windows Phone Power Tools on your Pc to look through applications data folders, however that only works with sideloaded applications.